# Regex to find two words : bait & bated

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am trying to find two words in a sentence , either one word or both may exist in the sentence .Words are `bait` and `bated`

I am trying to use the concept of capturing group and was able to get the two words using the below regex `ba(?:it)?(?:ted)?` .The problem with this is that it returns 
`ba` for words like balance or bala etc...

Can it possible to get a regex of the similar structure but without matching `ba`?

Comment: Use word boundaries. `\bba(?:it)?(?:ted)?\b` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2Lj8XF/1)

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi That matches just "ba" too, though.

Comment: @Wiseguy: Sorry you are right. Actually it should have been `\b(?:bated|bait)\b`

Comment: Try this regex `ba(i)?t(ed)?`